# error while using javastreamingcontext with sparkconf object to consume from a kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

this is the error that i am getting when i am trying to run a java program locally on spark

```
 INFO org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI  - Started SparkUI at http://****.***.***:4041
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)V
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.<init>(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:36)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.<init>(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.<clinit>(SparkHadoopUtil.scala)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:228)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.createNewSparkContext(StreamingContext.scala:549)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.<init>(JavaStreamingContext.scala:130)
at com.zdatainc.rts.spark.SentimentAnalysis.main(SentimentAnalysis.java:38)
```

Here goes the code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.*;

import org.apache.spark.streaming.*;

import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.*;

import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.*;

import scala.Tuple2;

import scala.Tuple4;

import scala.Tuple5;

import java.util.*;

public class SentimentAnalysis

{

private final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());


private static final String KAFKA_TOPIC =           Properties.getString("rts.spark.kafka_topic");

private static final int KAFKA_PARALLELIZATION =
    Properties.getInt("rts.spark.kafka_parallelization");

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    BasicConfigurator.configure();
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                     .setAppName("Twitter Sentiment Analysis");

    if (args.length > 0)
        conf.setMaster(args[0]);
    else
        conf.setMaster("local[2]");

    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf,new Duration(2000));

    Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    topicMap.put(KAFKA_TOPIC, KAFKA_PARALLELIZATION);

    JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages =
        KafkaUtils.createStream(
            ssc,
            Properties.getString("rts.spark.zkhosts"),
            "twitter.sentimentanalysis.kafka",
            topicMap);
```

here is the rts.kafka.properties

```
rts.spark.zkhosts: node0,node2,node4
rts.spark.webserv: http://node0:3000/post
rts.spark.kafka_topic: twitter.tweet
rts.spark.kafka_parallelization: 4
rts.spark.hdfs_output_dir: hdfs://node0/user/spark/${rts.spark.kafka_topic}
rts.spark.hdfs_output_file: ${rts.spark.hdfs_output_dir}/scores
```

i have tried searching everything but nothing has worked out for me yet.
I am new to this please help.i am trying to receive messages from kafka topic and transfer them through spark streaming and then store it in hdfs.
[this is link from where i have taken the code](https://github.com/zdata-inc/SparkSampleProject)

here are all the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.3</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.3</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
<version>0.20.2</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
  <version>1.9</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Provide please your dependency and cluster hadoop/spark version?

Comment: i have edited the post. thanks in advance.